# How to add query provider for spring data?

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

In MyBatis we can annotate by `@ServiceProvider` and bind the query from the Java class.  I want to do same thing using Spring Boot JPA.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please visit [How to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using **spring-data-jpa-extra** project https://github.com/slyak/spring-data-jpa-extra

it covers

- dynamic native query support like mybatis
- return type can be anything
- no code, just sql